# Jquery DataTable calling in dropdown change event issue

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm stuck on simple point in jquery datatable. I have dropdown selection and according to it, it should have to populate data in datatable.

> TRY 1

Here is the code.

```
//code in $(document).ready(function () { ............
$("#drpRestaurants").on('change', function () {
    var restId = $(this).val();
    getBranches(restId);

});

 //ajax call of datatable
function getBranches(restId) {

    var data1 = { "restaurantId": restId };

    resturantBranchTable = $("#BranchList").DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": serverLocation + "/api/dashboard/getBranches",
            "type": "post",
            "data": JSON.stringify(data1),
            "dataSrc": ""
        },
        "ordering": false,
        columns: [
            { title: 'Id', data: 'id' },
            { title: 'Restaurant', data: 'restaurant.restaurantName' },
            { title: 'Branch Location', data: 'brachLocation' },
            { title: 'Branch Address', data: 'brachAddress' },
            { title: 'Contact No', data: 'telephoneNo' },
            { title: 'Is Active', data: 'isActive' }
        ],
    });    
}
```

When I select 1st time, it is successfully filled data to datatable. But when i'm going to select 2nd time, it is throw an error. (Below I copy and paste it)

*DataTables warning: table id=BranchList - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3*

The error is simply say that, the issue is i'm going to reinitialize the datatable. But I have lack of knowledge to do it. I know that, in document.ready can initialize the datatable like beolw.

```
resturantBranchTable = $("#BranchList").DataTable();
```

But in that case, how to data bind in dropdown change event?

> TRY 2

```
  //document.ready function

   var data1 = { "restaurantId": restId };

    resturantBranchTable = $("#BranchList").DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": serverLocation + "/api/dashboard/getBranches",
            "type": "post",
            "data": JSON.stringify(data1),
            "dataSrc": ""
        },
        "ordering": false,
        columns: [
            { title: 'Id', data: 'id' },
            { title: 'Restaurant', data: 'restaurant.restaurantName' },
            { title: 'Branch Location', data: 'brachLocation' },
            { title: 'Branch Address', data: 'brachAddress' },
            { title: 'Contact No', data: 'telephoneNo' },
            { title: 'Is Active', data: 'isActive' }
        ],
    });   


   //drop down change event
   $("#drpRestaurants").on('change', function () {
       restId = $(this).val(); //This restId  is global variable
       resturantBranchTable.ajax.reload();
   });
```

This also doesn't work....

> TRY 3 (Solution)

I just found a better solution. (Honestly I dont know whether this is a better one. How ever this worked fine for me).

First initialize the data table in document ready fucntion.

```
resturantBranchTable = $('#BranchList').DataTable({

    columns: [
            { title: 'Id', data: 'id' },
            { title: 'Restaurant', data: 'restaurant.restaurantName' },
            { title: 'Branch Location', data: 'brachLocation' },
            { title: 'Branch Address', data: 'brachAddress' },
            { title: 'Contact No', data: 'telephoneNo' },
            { title: 'Is Active', data: 'isActive' }
        ],

});
```

Then we can get data from ajax call and bind data like this.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: serverLocation + "/api/dashboard/getBranches",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(requestJson),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        success: function (response) {
            resturantBranchTable.clear().draw(); //clear the data table 
            resturantBranchTable.rows.add(response).draw(); //after clearing, bind data
        },
        error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('Err');
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps to others who stuck in their projects.

Comment: you can find this solutio: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62359062/reload-datatable-after-dropdown-value-changed

Answer (score 0):

Separate the initial call from the refresh/reload call, using the value or non-value of the variable pointing to the DataTable as the thing you branch on.

```
var resturantBranchTable;

$("#drpRestaurants").on('change', function () {
   restId = $(this).val(); //This restId  is global variable
   if (!resturantBranchTable) {
       getBranches(restId);
   } else {
      resturantBranchTable.ajax.reload();
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @joe. Actually I've found some other solution. Please see my "TRY 3".